# Version Control for each item programmatically in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, version-control, version

I want to store different number of versions for each item in a single library depending upon the flag.
I know out-of the box feature would apply at document library level, but I want to do it at item level with customization.
Any idea , how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the DocLib settings to unlimited (our your max) number of versions

And then implement an SPItemEventReceiver where you're deleting versions in the ItemUpdated/ItemCheckedIn events